# Animation Nodes - Extract single object from group to perform independent translations

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a simple setup that uses "Objects from Group" to then do some falloff translations on the group.  I need to isolate a specific object in that group to perform an independent translation on it after the falloff translations.

I'm not an expert with AN but after fiddling around with "Loop Through Objects" functionality from the "Objects from Group" node, I have been unable to isolate the object I need from the group using varios "list" and "get" nodes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've solved this by using "Get List Element fed into "Object Transforms Output" in my setup.  However this only started working as soon as I added a viewer node (debug) to the Get List Element node to ensure the data was there.  I don't have an explanation as to why the setup would kick in to action once a view node was invoked.  Strange but I suspect it's some kind of coding glitch.

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  Unable to get any consistent behavior on this in 2.79 with AN 2.0.4 (latest production release). It works sometimes then not others.  Very unstable.  : /

Comment: Can you show us the node tree? Maybe provide the blend file?

Comment: I can't share this particular one since it's a client project but I will build another file to demonstrate.

Comment: Here's a sample file with a mockup showing the intended process.  The flow should be fairly straightforward.  I've included viewer nodes along the way to show validation that the objects are being fed through until the end.

The intended outcome is to be able to independently control the translation of each object in a group before it then gets processed by the next stage of timeline based falloff translations.  

File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc6ddd7on54q0c4/AN_XF_Override_Bugs.blend?dl=0

Comment: How do you want to *"independently control the translation"*?

Comment: As an amendment to the translations that occur in the procedural falloff translations.  Eg, all objects are already being driven to translate in from whatever vectors as shown in the file but the user has the ability to tweak any specific object translation vector they wish via index selection from the group. 

This is a common real world example where you have 20 objects in motion and an art director says, "Hey grab object #12 and rotate it another 45 degrees within this existing animation."

Answer (score 3):

Let us first simply your node tree into something that is more efficient. Since you are not using matrices and setting the rotation and locations independently, we can use a vectorized *Object Transforms Output* node to do both. Moreover, since you are only offsetting the location component of the matrices, we can use a vectorized *Offset Vector* instead. So our node tree reduces to:

[image: Node Tree]

If you want to edit the translation of each object independently, you can input the custom translation vectors into the *offset* input, for instance, we can translate the first and thrid objects in the opposite direction as follows:

[image: Variable Offset]

What if you want to animate the rotation? Simply offset zero vectors, convert them to eulers and set them to the objects:

[image: Eulers]

Want to implement a non animated offset? Add the offset vectors after the time based falloff offset:

[image: Offset]

Comment: This did the trick.  Great thing about AN is that you never run short on learning about nodes hiding under the hood lol.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @VFXTobias Please accept the answer if it answers your question.